# Solve the inequality $\frac 1{x+1} - \frac 1{x} \le \frac 1{x-1} - \frac 1{x-2}$

Tags: inequality

$$\frac 1{x+1} - \frac 1{x} \le \frac 1{x-1} - \frac 1{x-2}$$

The answer for this inequality is given as $x ∈ (- \infty , -1) \cup(0, 1) \cup (2, \infty)$ but when I solve it, I am only able to get $x ∈ ( - \infty, -1)$.

How should I solve it to get the complete answer?

Comment: Unless you show the steps it is difficult to say where you are going wrong.

Comment: That is not the complete solution. For example $x=1.1$ satisfies the inequality

Comment: The answer you've given isn't even correct. For example, take $x=5$.

Comment: Yes, I suppose the answer given in my reference material is wrong. Thank you for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 2):

Go step by step:
$$\frac 1{x+1} - \frac 1{x} \le \frac 1{x-1} - \frac 1{x-2} \\
\frac{-1}{x(x+1)} \le \frac{-1}{(x-2)(x-1)} \\
\frac{1}{(x-2)(x-1)} - \frac{1}{x(x+1)} \le 0 \\
\frac{x(x+1) - (x-2)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)} \le 0 \\
\frac{x^2+x - (x^2-3x+2)}{(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)} \le 0 \\
\frac{4x-2}{(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)} \le 0$$
Can you finish this now?

Comment: Ok, I get this. Instead of subtracting the expressions, I was trying to cross multiply them the whole time. Thank you! :)

Comment: @VIVID The constant term in the last two lines was not correct. Just edited it. Otherwise it would have lead to a partly wrong solution.

Comment: @trancelocation Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Solve the Inequality :$$\frac 1{x+1} - \frac 1{x} \le \frac 1{x-1} - \frac 1{x-2} \\$$

$$\frac{-1}{x(x+1)} \le \frac{-1}{(x-2)(x-1)} \\$$

Consider two scenarios :

scenario 1 : **Less than**

$$\frac{-1}{x(x+1)}~< \frac{-1}{(x-2)(x-1) }$$.

$$\frac{-1~(x^2-x-2x+2)}{x(x+1)}+1~<0$$

$$\frac{(4~x~-2)}{x~(~x+1)}~<0$$

$$x \in (-\infty , \frac{1}{2}) $$

Scenario 2 : **equal to**

$$\frac{-1}{x(x+1)}~=\frac{-1}{(x-2)(x-1) }$$.

$$\frac{-1~(x^2-x-2x+2)}{x(x+1)}+1~=0$$

$$\frac{(4~x~-2)}{x~(~x+1)}~=0$$

$$ x = \frac{1}{2}$$

Final step : $$x \in (-\infty , \frac{1}{2}] $$

Comment: In scenario1 you cannot  cross multiply without taking separate cases because the terms can be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to tackle this problem:
\begin{align}\frac 1{x+1} - \frac 1{x}=-\frac 1{x(x+1)} &\le \frac 1{x-1} - \frac 1{x-2}= -\frac 1{(x-2)(x-1)}\\
\iff \frac{1}{(x-2)(x-1)}&\le  \frac{1}{x(x+1)} 
\end{align}
Now observe that:

- outside of $\,(-1,0)\cup(1,2)$, both denominators are positive, so
  $$\frac{1}{(x-2)(x-1)}\le  \frac{1}{x(x+1)}\iff x(x+1)\le(x-2)(x-1)\iff 4x\le 2.$$
- In $(-1,0)$ and in $(1,2)$, compare the signs of the denominators.